# Can we reject app after getting apple approval?

Tags: iphone, app-store, release

I have uploaded new binary as a new version of my application and at the time of uploading binary, I select the option that "I Will Release this version".

Suppose my application is approved by apple But I dont want to release that version.

Is it possible to reject that binary or remove that version from iTunes connect?

Comment: You should change the accepted answer. Come on....

Comment: Look to the top right .. it's so silly

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes you can reject it!

Click on your "**New version**" > "**Binary Details**" > "**Reject Binary**"

[image]

Comment: The button is still present. Just rejected an app after approval. It's in the Binary Details.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://s4.postimg.org/rsofa5jzh/Schermata_2014_03_28_alle_12_35_56.png)

Comment: This is the proper way to reject a binary, but you cannot reject a binary at all times...there are only certain app statuses when this is possible (granted, your app is likely to have one of these statuses).  For instance, if you are pending contract, you cannot reject a binary.  [Apple's docs](http://bit.ly/XQz4q8) for rejecting a binary make this very clear:

You can reject the binary you’ve submitted if its status is any of the following:

Missing Screenshot (iOS only)
Waiting For Export Compliance
Waiting For Review
In Review
Pending Developer Release
Pending Apple Release

Comment: This was correct 12 years ago, it no longer exists.  See the modern answers.

Answer (score 6):

To reject a approved release, select the approved release in iTunesConnect and at the top of the profile is a link "Cancel this release"

[image]

Comment: Funny that I kept scrolling right past this big blue banner at the top looking for a button somewhere. I ended up coming to stackoverflow (like I do for all of life's problems) and yours is the only up-to-date answer. Somehow I missed the blue banner.

Comment: Ditto @spartygw.  I don't know why it was so hard to find that link but it was and I thought I'd spare others from having to venture into that same black hole of time.

Answer (score 3):

Paras, once you submit a new binary, it goes to the end of the queue for review!

I see a few possible cases related with your question:

1. You have no app yet, you submitted an app and waiting for review. Assume that you found a problem with the submitted app, and you wanted to provide a new one. Just submit the new binary, but remember, it will replace the original submission, it will go to the end of the queue and it will wait for review as before.
2. You have an app on the AppStore, and you wanted to provide an update for the app. As usual, submit your app, and wait to be notified. Once it is approved, your new app will be available to your users.
3. You have an app on the AppStore, you want to remove it from sales immediately, and provide an update: In this case, you can go to Manage Your Apps in your iTunes Connect, select the app and click on Rights and Pricing then choose an Availability Date in the future.

You get a warning message as following:
"You have selected an Available Date in the future. This will remove your currently live version from the App Store until the new date. Changing Available Date affects all versions of the application, both Ready For Sale and In Review."

That is fine, your app still in the store but not be in the sales. Now you provide your update and wait for the approval, once you get it, go ahead and set your app's availability date accordingly!

I hope that answers your question, and good luck on the mobile apps :)

Comment: This answer is completely outdated. Please ignore it

Answer (score 1):

You can remove your app from the AppStore any time you want.

For that, simply **go to itunesconnect.apple.com** and on the "**Manage your Application**", choose the "**Rights & Pricing**" button then click on the "**specific stores**" link.

From there you can select in which stores your app will be in sale. You can then **deselect all the countries so that your app won't be visible in *any* store**.

---

*From the iTunes Connect portal:*

> Select the App Stores where your app will be sold. Note that if you deselect all territories, your app will be removed from sale in all App Stores worldwide.

Comment: This is completely unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

## The button is absurdly positioned to your top right:

[image]

It's a html link instead of a normal button.

Answer (score -1):

It appears that you can not reject a app after it is approved by Apple.  One possible sequence is to release the approved version for sale in only some tiny country for an hour, then remove it from sale and submit a new update.

Comment: This answer is outdated. Please ignore it

Answer (score -1):

Bit of an update.

If you have an app with Developer Release and
The app has been approved then
The Web iTunes Connect does not provide any method to reject the binary, only a release button.

There is however a Reject Binary option still available on the iPhone iTunesConnect App.

So if you find yourself with this issue

1. Start the iTunesConnect App
2. Select the manage option
3. Tap on your apps pending version release
4. Select the 'Reject Binary' button

Hope that helps.

Comment: I can't see this in the current version.

Comment: Outdated answer, both on the first assumption (that you can't do it on the web) and on the app.

Comment: This is completely wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I was not an admin but an app manager in App Store Connect. I did not have permission to remove the app but I was able to withdraw from the sale in order to pull back acceptance.

Pricing and Availability -> Availability -> Remove from sale

[image]

Comment: This is totally unrelated. Don't do this or the app will be removed forever.