# Can you remove an app update in iTunes Connect after its been accepted

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect

If I submit an update to an iOS application via iTunes connect and set the release date for some distant date in the future, will I be able to remove/cancel that update even once it gets accepted?

UPDATED:

shortly after adding this, I found the following:

[Rejecting an app that is Pending Developer Release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792402/rejecting-an-app-that-is-pending-developer-release)

[can we reject app after getting apple approval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560514/can-we-reject-app-after-getting-apple-approval)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Rejecting an app that is Pending Developer Release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792402/rejecting-an-app-that-is-pending-developer-release)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in iTunesConnect.  Here's how to remove an app from sale: (this is from the iTunesConnect developer guide).

- Click on the "Rights and Pricing"￼ button from your App Summary Page.
- Click on the link to view specific stores.
- Click on "Deselect All" to    uncheck all App Store territories.
- Click on the "Save Changes" button.

If the App hasn't been released yet (it is "Pending Developer Release"), use "Reject This Binary" instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think you may have slightly misunderstood the question. I understand what you have described from removing an "application" from sale, however, in this case I am directly referring  to an update on the application that is submitted, accepted, but not released yet (staus = "Pending Dev Release"). So i guess plainly stated = can you reject binary of an update thats already been accepted but still pending dev release?

Comment: Yes, you can reject a binary that is pending developer release.  I've done it myself a few times when I realized I needed to make changes after Apple had approved an app.

Comment: From the iTunes Connect documentation: "When the status of your app is Missing Screenshot (iOS only), Waiting for Export Compliance, Waiting For Review, In Review, Pending Developer Release or Pending Apple Release you can reject the binary you have submitted by clicking Reject Binary from the Binary Details page. This removes your binary from the review queue, and you can then submit another update through Application Loader once you move your app back to the Waiting For Upload state in iTunes Connect. If you reject your binary, the status of your app will change to Developer Rejected. "

Answer (score 0):

You can now "Cancel This Release" after it has been approved and the state of yur app is "Pending Developer Release".

Which I think it's a little bit of an overkill as you shouldn't need to do that. But it's nice to have it.